# Problems while reformating a list of tuples, by taking only the first value of the tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have the following list of tuples:

```
>>>lis = df['vals'].values.tolist()
>>>lis
[[('apple', 'FRUIT'),
          ('$', 'SYM'),
          ('6.00', 'X'),
          ('bannana', 'FRUIT'),
          ('$', 'SYM'),
          ('4.00', 'X')]]
```

How can I reformat it into:

```
lis = [['apple: $ 6.00', 'bannana: $ 4.00']]
```

I tried to:

```
list_comp = [item for sublist in lis for item in sublist]
list_comp = [' '.join(item) for t in list_comp for item in [t]]
```

However I do not get how to put the `:` and the above format.

Comment: `[[apple: $ 6.00 bannana: $ 4.00]]` this is not a python type. what/which any of the parts is? string? number? are they different values inside a list? is that 1 list of 1 list of 1 item which is a string?

Comment: check the second block of code in your question. What is going on there?

Comment: update the question because it's really not clear.

Comment: Do you want it as `"apple: $ 6.00 bannana: $ 4.00"` (one string), or `['apple:', '$', '6.00', 'bannana:', '$', '4.00']` (list of strings)? And why there are two lists there? `[ [  ] ]` ?

Comment: I want to flat it into: `[ ['apple: $ 6.00', 'bannana: $ 4.00']].` @Dekel

Comment: but your original data is a list that contains 1 list  of many tuples. how are they divided?

Comment: @Dekel by commas, thats the problem.... I need to wrangle it and I do not know how to. Well it is actually a pandas dataframe tha's why it has this form: `[ [ ] ]`

Comment: @Dekel, I just take a the values of the column into a list, check my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a comprehension and concatenate `": $ "` with the tuple elements:

```
print [lis[0][i][0] + ": $ " + lis[0][i+2][0] for i in range(0,len(lis[0]),3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, define a function:

```
>>> def format_tuple(fruit, sym, x):
...   return "{}: {} {}".format(fruit, sym, x)
...
```

Then,

```
>>> my_list
[[('apple', 'FRUIT'), ('$', 'SYM'), ('6.00', 'X'), ('bannana', 'FRUIT'), ('$', 'SYM'), ('4.00', 'X')]]
>>> my_list = my_list[0]
>>> by_three = (my_list[i:i + 3] for i in range(0,len(my_list), 3))
>>> [format_tuple(*(c[0] for c in chunk)) for chunk in by_three]
['apple: $ 6.00', 'bannana: $ 4.00']
```

And, I suppose if you really want it wrapped in a list, that last line could be:

```
>>> [[format_tuple(*(c[0] for c in chunk)) for chunk in by_three]]
[['apple: $ 6.00', 'bannana: $ 4.00']]
```